# C# Convert from IPEndPoint to Socket

Tags: c#, server, client, communication

I have a server which works fine. But I think the way I am passing strings from a server to client is not the right way.
This is my current approach in server.

```
                    foreach (Socket _connectedUsers in clientSockets)
                    {
                        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("Text");
                        Socket socket = (Socket)_connectedUsers;
                        socket.Send(data);
                    }
```

In this approach it is sending string to all connected clients. But I want to be able to specify particular socket and send it to one unique connected client.

I know that I can identify IP and PORT of any connected socket by using this function:

```
         IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = current.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
```

This function allows me to see what IP and port number current socket has.

But lets say I get entire list of connected sockets and get them as 'IPEndPoint' list. How can I convert it into socket to do something like this?

```
IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = current.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
Socket SendToSocket = remoteIpEndPoint as Socket; //I know this is wrong.. How can I convert it to socket?
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server can Hear you");
SendToSocket.Send(data);
```

How can I convert IPEndPoint or string with IP and Port or anything else into Socket?

I think I explained my question in very detail.
If you have any other suggestions or techniques how I could make this possible, please help. :)

Also it is worth to mention why I don't want to use 'foreach', because if I will stream my web camera in my app, I don't want to stream to everyone because 'foreach' is streaming for everyone. This is why I need to specify unique socket to avoid streaming and reduce traffic in other clients when they are not supposed to receive anything.

Comment: See Msdn Asychronous Listener (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example).  One listener is used for multiple clients.  The socket is passed to the ReadCallback and then you can send back to client on same socket that data was received.

Comment: So this would allow me to send string from a server to one individual client even if there are over 20 clients connected? And I could specify which one?

Comment: Create a List<StateObject>.  Then in accept method add each new stateobject to the list.  You can also have an endpoint (the ip address of each socket) so you can send to anybody.  I sometimes create a dictionary of <IP, StateObject> so you can look up any particular IP.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you, but I don't find an issue with finding list of IP addresses I want to send to . I can't understand how can I assign IP,PORT to socket so I could send it. 
List will make for me another 'foreach' loop that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: The StateObject has a workSocket.  The worksocket has a local and remote endpoint.  The remote endpoint that has the client IP address.  You cannot send TCP to an IP address .  You first need a connection.  You already have the connection(s) in the workSocket.  You can create a dictionary with IP and workSocket so you can avoid the foreach loop.

Comment: @jdweng Right, I'ts kinda makes sense. I need to investigate this and play around with it.

Comment: @jdweng I am sorry for asking, but would it be possible to provide in solution section an example how would you add them?

Comment: You have to cast EndPoint to IPEndPoint :             IPEndPoint ep = (IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            IPAddress address = ep.Address;
            string addressStr = address.ToString();